# Is there any way to change quality of image exported from pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, image, pyqt, export, pyqtgraph

I have a simple question. How to improve the quality of the exported image from pyqtgraph, using the [export API](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exporting.html#exporting-from-the-api)  ?

When I used the GUI export tool, the exported image looks like this in my GUI. If I'm not using the GUI but instead using code to export from `pyqtgraph` docs, the image looks terrible. In particular, fonts are compressed and "rasterized". I attach both exported images.

Code(API) exported

[image]

GUI exported

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to read the options of the exporter using `help()` or simply reading the source code?

Comment: Yes, i have read the code. I have no idea how to start help() on this package. The exporters (ImageExporter) has only attribute 'antialias' which could be useful, but it had not any impact on the rendering. The second question is, which method is call by Export in GUI? I try to start debug and finding, but breakpoints in ImageExporter hadn't stop the code. Probably the API and GUI export are different functions.

Comment: `help()` can be called in the interactive python shell. I cannot answer the other question, but can always open the source code of the pyqtgraph package and so a search for that function call and definition.